# Highcharts Detect mouseOver event only in the colored area

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts, mouseover

I have an 'Area' type series, I need to detect when the user mouse over **only** in the colored area in order to render a label there.

I can see it is possible to catch the "click" event in the colored area, but it is not possible to catch the "mouseOver" **only** in that colored area since the event is also triggered when you are positioned above the area (when trackByArea=true)

Here is an example describing the issue:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'USA',
    data: [6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
      1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444
    ],

    trackByArea: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',

    events: {
      //Click event is triggered only inside the area
      click: function(event) {
        alert('Trigger Drilldown')
      },
      //mouseOver event is triggered inside and above the area
      mouseOver: function(event) {
        console.log('TriggermouseOver')
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

As side note I realized this should be possible since the cursor is being updated when over inside the area. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `stickyTracking: false,` in plot options

```
plotOptions: {
 series: {
  stickyTracking: false,
 }
},
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stickyTracking: false,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'USA',
    data: [6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
      1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444
    ],

    trackByArea: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',

    events: {
      //Click event is triggered only inside the area
      click: function(event) {
        alert('Trigger Drilldown')
      },
      //mouseOver event is triggered inside and above the area
      mouseOver: function(event) {
        console.log('TriggermouseOver')
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Great, you save my day, thanks!  It was confusing for me the combination of both fields "stickyTracking" and "trackByArea", the problem could be that both fields have different default values pre-loaded. (doc https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.stickyTracking)